# A problem occurred configuring project ':network_info_plus'

Tags: android

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':network_info_plus:classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10.
> Required by:
> project :network_info_plus
> > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally. However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10:
> - gradle70JavadocElements
> - gradle70RuntimeElements
> - gradle70SourcesElements
> - javadocElements
> - runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute
> - sourcesElements
> All of them match the consumer attributes:
> - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'gradle70RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'gradle70SourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
> The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
> - Variant 'apiElementsWithFixedAttribute' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
> - Variant 'gradle70ApiElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':network_info_plus' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':network_info_plus' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

network_info_plus classes Already added my Project but Show a above error